# Flexible group buttons in absolute position

Tags: html, css

I know the answer seems easy, but I've searched everything on the internet and can not find anything.

I have 5 buttons that work with relative position. I'm curious if I can use absolute position in any way.
Of course, the buttons must be flex, ie if the page is stretched, the buttons must be stretched as well (without media queries).
Τhank you very much!!!.

```css
.flexible {
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
}

#one, #two, #three, #four, #five {
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  top:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
#one:hover, #two:hover, #three:hover, #four:hover, #five:hover { 
  background: #9a009a;  
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<center class="flexible">
<button id="one">1</button>
<button id="two">2</button>
<button id="three">3</button>
<button id="four">4</button>
<button id="five">5</button>
</center>
```

Comment: No, I think you can't achive this with absolute positioning in a way that does not include non-css approach. Can you give us some context, why is absolute positioning must?

Comment: short answer is yes, but you will have to be a little more specific with what you want. as long as you apply `position: relative;` to the `flexible`-element (the parent container), the child elements with `position: absolute;` will be positioned relative to its parent container - so it will work responsively as well (for the most part - again, depends what you want)

Comment: It could be used for various reasons.
  For example 5 buttons (6,7,8,9,10) just behind these 5 and work with z-index (Front-Back).
or a dropdown menu with absolute position in some specific li, etc. The question is, how could it be done here in the above example, any idea would be very useful! Thanks

Comment: To whom do you want to apply the absolute position? To the parent? To all the children? To an specific child? In other words: what's your ultimate goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can but it remain a very specific solution to your specific case. It's not a generic solution

```css
#one, #two, #three, #four, #five {
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100%/5); /* 20% */
}
#one   {left: calc(0*100%/5)} /* 0%  */
#two   {left: calc(1*100%/5)} /* 20% */
#three {left: calc(2*100%/5)} /* 40% */
#four  {left: calc(3*100%/5)} /* 60% */
#five  {left: calc(4*100%/5)} /* 80% */

[id]:hover {
  background: #9a009a;
}
```

```html
<button id="one">1</button>
<button id="two">2</button>
<button id="three">3</button>
<button id="four">4</button>
<button id="five">5</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you use `position` for the children at all, while you used `flex` for container. But you can give the `position: absolute` to `.flexible` if it is proper for you:

```css
.flexible {
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

button {
  background: purple;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
button:hover { 
  background: #9a009a;  
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<center class="flexible">
<button id="one">1</button>
<button id="two">2</button>
<button id="three">3</button>
<button id="four">4</button>
<button id="five">5</button>
</center>
```